# Protractor generates an error when disabling flow control to test an Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I've been struggling with this error for a while and I'm running out of mana. I'm currently trying to test an *Angular* app with protractor and async/await. According to the doc, I have to disable the control flow by adding the following to my config file:

`SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` but doing so produces the following error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"` I visited the url (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643) but it didn't turn out very helpful.

At this point I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug with protractor itself. For this reason I also [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5150).

Here is my test:

```
import {
    browser,
    ExpectedConditions,
    $
} from 'protractor';

describe('When user click \"Test\" button', async () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('myawesomewebsite');
  });

  it ("should click the button", async () => {
    var button = $(".button");
    button.click();
  });
});
```

And here is my full configuration:

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['test.spec.ts'],
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },    
  beforeLaunch: function () {
    require('ts-node/register')
  }
};
```

Comment: Is your login page also in angular?

Comment: Yes. The whole app is developed with Angular.

Comment: I noticed you removed your answer regarding setting waitForAngularEnabled to true, Is this still an open question or have you resolved it?

Comment: Yes I resolved it, but indeed the conf was wrong, I'll post my answer, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

You missed `await` before each protractor api invoking.

```
describe('When user click \"Test\" button', async () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('myawesomewebsite');
  });

  it ("should click the button", async () => {
    var button = $(".button");
    await button.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Yong, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not my problem. I could not use async/await properly due to project misconfiguration, but I figured out what to use thanks to my post on Github.

Thanks again for taking the time to read and help though, I appreciate :D

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to @CrispusDH on GitHub, I figured out that I could use `waitForAngularEnabled` in the configuration file and not just in the spec file. Using it in the spec file was not working, but if used in the `onPrepare` hook of the configuration file, the error goes away.

A lot of resources online were saying to set it to false, but this wasn't working for me as Protractor couldn't find element without waiting for Angular, so I did set it to false in the configuration and file but called `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` in my specs file (beforeAll hook). Now the error is gone, allowing me to use `async/await`.

Here is the proper configuration to use:

```
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  onPrepare: async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  }
```

And here is the code to call in spec file:

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
  });
```